# Max length 255 preventing form submission despite longer StringLength

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm attempting to create a form that will allow a User to submit new records to a SQL Server database that will ultimately be displayed on the site. I have a `Description` field that on the server side is an **nvarchar(max)**. In my Model ive specified a String length over 255 (ie. 500, 1000) I've used `StringLength(Int32.MaxLength)`. I've tried disabling client side validation, excluding validation entirely from the input and have had no luck. But, when running the code locally it functions as expected and allows form submission but when deployed to a live GoDaddy site via FTP (with the same code) it still throws the MaxLength validation error `The field Description must be a string with a maximum length of 255.`

## Boar.cs

```
namespace ShipleySwine
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;

    public partial class Boar
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Boar()
        {
            SellingPoints = new HashSet<SellingPoint>();
        }

        [Key]
        [Column(TypeName = "numeric")]
        public decimal Boar_Id { get; set; }

        [StringLength(255)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public DateTime? Farrowed { get; set; }

        public int? LitterSize { get; set; }

        public int? Price { get; set; }

        public bool? GuaranteedSettle { get; set; }

        [StringLength(255)]
        public string StressTest { get; set; }

        [StringLength(255)]
        public string NameNoSpaces { get; set; }

        [StringLength(255)]
        public string Sire { get; set; }

        [StringLength(255)]
        public string SireFull { get; set; }

        [StringLength(255)]
        public string Dam { get; set; }

        [StringLength(255)]
        public string DamFull { get; set; }

        [StringLength(255)]
        public string Breed { get; set; }

        public int? Order { get; set; }

        public bool? Featured { get; set; }

        public int? FeaturedOrder { get; set; }

        [StringLength(255)]
        public string EarNotch { get; set; }

        [StringLength(255)]
        public string RegNum { get; set; }

        [StringLength(255)]
        public string TestData { get; set; }

        [StringLength(255)]
        public string BredBy { get; set; }

        [StringLength(255)]
        public string OwnedBy { get; set; }

        [StringLength(500)]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public DateTime? CreateDate { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<SellingPoint> SellingPoints { get; set; }
    }
}
```

## Create.cshtml (Towards the bottom: Description Field)

```
@model ShipleySwine.Boar



@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<div class="container backgroundcolor">
    <h2>Create</h2>


    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <h4>Boar</h4>
            <hr />
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <div class="form-group">
                @*@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Boar_Id, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })*@
                <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Boar_id">Boar ID</label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <input name="Boar_id" class="form-control" value="@ViewBag.BoarId" readonly="readonly" />
                    @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Boar_Id, new { htmlAttributes = new { placeholder = "Ex: 1" , @class = "form-control" } })*@
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Boar_Id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { placeholder = "Ex: Gavin", @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Farrowed, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Farrowed, new { htmlAttributes = new { placeholder = "Ex: 2015-07-10", @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Farrowed, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LitterSize, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LitterSize, new { htmlAttributes = new { placeholder = "Ex: 5", @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LitterSize, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Price, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Price, new { htmlAttributes = new { placeholder = "Ex: 500", @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Price, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.GuaranteedSettle, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.GuaranteedSettle)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.GuaranteedSettle, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StressTest, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StressTest, new { htmlAttributes = new { placeholder = "Ex: Negative, Carrier", @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StressTest, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NameNoSpaces, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NameNoSpaces, new { htmlAttributes = new { placeholder = "Ex: GavinNoSpaces", @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NameNoSpaces, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Sire, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Sire, new { htmlAttributes = new { placeholder = "Ex: Daddy Boar", @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Sire, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SireFull, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SireFull, new { htmlAttributes = new { placeholder = "Ex: Daddy Boar Full Name", @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SireFull, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Dam, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Dam, new { htmlAttributes = new { placeholder = "Ex: Mommy Boar", @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Dam, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DamFull, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DamFull, new { htmlAttributes = new { placeholder = "Ex: Mommy Boar Full Name", @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DamFull, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Breed, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Breed, new { htmlAttributes = new { placeholder = "Ex: Yorkshire, Berkshire,Duroc", @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Breed, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Order, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Order, new { htmlAttributes = new { placeholder = "Ex: 5", @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Order, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Featured, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Featured)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Featured, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FeaturedOrder, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FeaturedOrder, new { htmlAttributes = new { placeholder = "Ex: 5", @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FeaturedOrder, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EarNotch, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EarNotch, new { htmlAttributes = new { placeholder = "Ex: E.N.: 23-5", @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EarNotch, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RegNum, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RegNum, new { htmlAttributes = new { placeholder = "Reg #: 490946005", @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RegNum, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TestData, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TestData, new { htmlAttributes = new { placeholder = "158 days to 250# 0.51 BF 9.38 LE", @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TestData, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BredBy, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BredBy, new { htmlAttributes = new { placeholder = "Bred By: Farrer Stock Farm (IN)", @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BredBy, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OwnedBy, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OwnedBy, new { htmlAttributes = new { placeholder = "Owned By: Shipley Swine Genetics, Snyder Berks and Austin Lane", @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OwnedBy, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { placeholder = "Add something here", @class = "form-control" } })

                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10 text-center">
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }

    <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index", "Boars")
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: *but when deployed to a live GoDaddy site via FTP (with the same code) it still throws the MaxLength validation error* i dont believe the problem is in the code. do double check the database and code that runs in godaddy. also, you might want recycle your application pool. oh, before recycling, do double check if you have client side validation.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code as far as i can tell. If the project is connecting to a production database, can you check that to see if there is no constraint on there. Also, check if the client side validation isn't messing things up.